# What if tornadoes could open a wormhole?

Tags: wormholes

What if a tornado opened a wormhole to space? It would be an [EF 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Fujita_scale#Parameters) on the [Enhanced Fujita Scale]. It would open up on the top of the tornado. It is fast enough to make the wormhole stable? Would Earth be pulled through it?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: It would rather be the other way around: open a wormhole to space and you will have a tornado right there. Think: pulling the plug out of the bath tub.

Comment: @scienceerror, since we have lots of tornadoes on our planet but none of them has ever opened a worm hole, I would assume the answer is then a straight "NO".

Comment: How scientific do you want an answer to be? Because if your answer is even a little then mine is no. However there is nothing stopping you adding magic to your story and making it happen. In that case, however, anything is possible and I'm not sure where we can help. Perhaps if you think about the answer you want and get back to us. Also, welcome to world building :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! At the moment it is pretty unclear what you are asking specifically. Do you want to know what the consequences for people on earth would be? Or something entirely different? Your question might get put on hold. This is a standard procedure to make questions fit the site. The community will try to fix the question together with you, the author. You might also want to have a look at the [tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). Have fun!

Comment: You can't get more energy out of a system than is already there. So, tornadoes can't open wormholes, unless the energy in the tornado is greater than the energy required to open and maintain a stable wormhole.

Comment: Your little edit helps a bit as I can start to think about your goal. But we need a bit more information. I am no expert regarding wormholes but you might want to talk about the specific size of your wormhole. I imagine a wormhole the size of a needle would be different from a wormhole the size of the whole tornado. And please elaborate what the Enhanced Fukita Scale means. But maybe someone with a bit more knowledge from the community can help here. Sources via links would be nice too. Also, I don't think Tornadoes can create a wormhole so please explain how you want your "magic" to happen

Comment: @scienceerror At present we do no even know if worm holes can exist, much less what they are or how they behave. This means that your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @scienceerror If anything can happen, then your question is answered. Make it happen. Handwave it.

Comment: @scienceerror with "anything can happen" attitude, asking "what if" is moot.

Comment: @scienceerror Please refrain from using Caps. MichaelK knows how this site works. You need to specify how you want to use magic if you want wormholes to exist as there is currently no way for us to know how how to create wormholes.

Comment: @scienceerror What Mołot just said: if your premise is "Anything can happen", then asking "What does happen?" is a completely moot because the answer is "Whatever you as an author decide will happen is what happens".

Comment: Please, visit [help center / asking](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking). We really want to help you, but this site is not your regular forum. Far from it. Your experience here won't be good until you'll understand the differences.

Comment: What happened to you is (probably) automatic question ban. To get out of it earlier, you need to improve this question, or post some **good** answers. Please keep im mind that edits that are not meant to improve this question, or posting bad answers, may only put you deeper in ban (make time longer). So either edit this question about tornados to make it really suitable for this site (see link from my comment above), or wait.

Answer (score 10):

Would a tornado open a wormhole? No.

Would the wormhole open at the top of the tornado? No.

Is a tornado fast enough to stabilize a wormhole? No.

Would the Earth be pulled through the wormhole? No.

For information about wormholes, please look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) and [here](http://www.space.com/20881-wormholes.html) and [here](http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/topics_blackholes_wormholes.html) and [here](http://www.popsci.com.au/space/space-travel/will-wormhole-travel-ever-be-possible,397177).

Wormholes are reasonably well understood scientific concept. Please do the research to get some understanding of what is involved with wormholes. There is an incredible difference between what can be achieved by tornadoes and what is needed to create a wormhole.

Comment: @scienceerror My answer is based on reality as we known it. If you are trying to create a world where it is possible for tornadoes to open wormholes, then reality as we known it would have to be rewritten accordingly. Fiction doesn't have to be "realistic". Although there are limits to how much a writer can change reality to suit their story. Readers can lose their suspension of disbelief if reality is changed too much or goes in directions that lack credibility. This something you may wish to edit into your question or not as the case may be.